# PyMongo update multiple records with multiple data

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to store data the data of my dictionary in my database via PyMongo.

```
client = MongoClient('ip', port)
db = client.test_database
hdd = db.hdd

        products[{
        'Speed' : 'a', 
        'Capacity' : 'b',
        'Format' : 'c'
        }
        {
        'Speed' : 'd',
        'Capacity' : 'e', 
        'Format': 'f'}] ...
```

My database has a table `hdd` with 7 fields and 4 of them are already filled. The values of `Speed`, `capacity` and `format` are `""` and need to be replaced with the data of `products`. I want to fill the empty fields with the data of the dictionary.
Is there a way to update `hdd` like that, and if it's possible, how?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I assume you have some sort of "_id" value associated with each set of values, so you know which document in your collection to update? Let's call that "product_id". You can update individual documents like:

```
for product, product_id in data:
    hdd.update({'_id': product_id},
               {'$set': {'Speed': products['Speed'],
                         'capacity': products['capacity'],
                         'format': products['format']}})
```

The first argument to update is a query that specifies which document to match, the second is a set of [update operations](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/).

If you're on MongoDB 2.6 or later and the latest PyMongo, use a bulk update:

```
bulk = hdd.initialize_ordered_bulk_op()
for product, product_id in data:
    bulk.find({'_id': product_id}).update({'$set': {'Speed': products['Speed'],
                                                   'capacity': products['capacity'],
                                                   'format': products['format']}})
bulk.execute()
```

The operations are buffered on the client, then they're all sent to the server and executed at once when you call "execute()". [Bulk update operations](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/examples/bulk.html) with PyMongo and MongoDB 2.6+ require fewer round trips to the server than traditional updates.

Comment: cannot you just pas a whole collection to the update_many method instead of iterating over them? Assuming you want to update all the records? <code>cursor = db.collection.update_many({}, myposts, upsert=True)</code>>

Comment: this just doesn't work for me. myposts is an array of documents.

Answer (score 2):

`initialize_ordered_bulk_op` shows as deprecated in my PyCharm (I have pymongo 3.9). Bulk updates can be done as follows:

```
replacements = [{ ObjectId("5fa994e96bfcb746d4935778"): "new_value"}]
bulk_ops = []
for _id, new_value in replacements.items():
    bulk_ops.append(
        UpdateOne(
            {"_id": _id},
            {"$set": {"old_key": new_value, "other_key": other_value}},
        ) 
    )
result = db.coll.bulk_write(bulk_ops)
pprint(result.bulk_api_result)
```